# Servlet Glass Fish

Tags: java, github, servlet, glassfish

Fiz uma aplicação ontem em java web usando Glass Fish e subi o projeto no github (https://github.com/DeveloperArthur/Praticas-de-programa-o/tree/master/1AplicacaoJavaWEB).

Cheguei no trabalho, baixei o projeto do github e não funcionou, na hora que eu envio os dados para o servlet, ele mostra o erro de "O arquivo não foi encontrado"

Minha dúvida é: Precisa de algo instalado na máquina para rodar o arquivo servlet .java ?

Comment: Confere se os Path estão corretos e a versão do Java

Comment: Estão, eu conferi !!
Na minha máquina funcionou de boa

Comment: Ele roda local mas não roda quando baixa na maquina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No caso do Glass Fish no netbeans, para rodar o servlet, é necessário startar o glass fish, logo, tem que ter um compilador instalado na máquina para executar o projeto

Somente baixar ele no PC sem nenhum compilador, nao vai rodar o servlet